# Flask unexpectedly redirects me to home, instead of /<username>

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask website (+SQL Alchemy), everything works as expected most of the times, but in 1 out of 10 times, the route `/<username>` redirects me to the homepage instead of checking if the username exists.

The route is implemented as follow:

```
@app.route("/<username>")
def profile_page(username):
    user_data = User.query.filter(User.username == username).first_or_404()
    content_data = content.query.filter(content.owner == user_data).all()
    return render_template('profile.html', user_data=user_data, content_data=content_data)
```

Most of the times it checks if the username exists and redirects me to the username page, or, if it doesn't exist, I get 404 - as expected.

However, 10% of the times, it doesn't even check for user_data (I tried with a print() and seems like it doesn't enter this route at all). In these cases it just redirects me to the homepage of my website.

Does anyone know why this could happen?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Include (tell us) a ```username``` that works and one that doesn't work

Comment: it's random. for a specific username it works 90% of the time and doesn't work for 10% of the times. The same happens if the username does not exist. 90% of the times it would give 404 (as expected) and 10% would just redirect me to the homepage

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, does this mean it skips the entire code in your route definition? You can add a print statement as the very first line after ```def profile_page(username):``` to find out if the route definition is being triggered

Comment: that's exactly what I did: I added a print statement as the very first line after `def`. and in the 10% of cases where it redirected to the home, the print did not get executed. (Obviously the print did get executed when the website behaved as expected: username page or 404). So my understanding is that, when the issue is present, the route definition does not get triggered at all.
thanks a lot for your help so far by the way. Do you have any insights on what could be happening? :( I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I suspect the issue is that you might be hitting the end point `/<username>/` instead of just `</username>` (the first one had a trailing slash, the second one doesn't.

If your Flask routes are defined without a trailing slash, then you must access it without a trailing slash. If on the other hand, you define your Flask route WITH a trailing slash, then it will redirect correctly when accessed without a trailing slash. See this [summary](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/17552) of what I'm trying to describe

In simple terms, try this

```
@app.route("/<username>/")
def profile_page(username):
```